# Laravel variable to where clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to extend one app to use my new Laravel app. In this scenario I am getting an unknown number of filters and I would like to forward them all to `where()` clause.

I have made something like this:

```
private function filterConverter($filter)
{
    $f = [];
    foreach ($filter as $singleFilter) {
        $operator = $this->filterValues[$singleFilter['operator']];
        $value = $operator == 'like' ? '%' . $singleFilter['value'] . '%' : $singleFilter['value'];

        $f[] = $singleFilter['field'] . ',' . $operator . ',' . $value;
    }

    return $f;
}
```

The thing is that I am getting operators like `EQUALS` and `CONTAINS` so I need to convert them to `=` and `LIKE`.

With this code I am trying to do this:

```
return response(MyModel::where($filter)->get());
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any elegant way to resolve this?

**EDIT/SOLUTION**

Sorry to [@HCK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7117697/hck) as I couldn't quite accept the answer since it doesn't answer my question, but it pointed me on the right track. The solution was to use `key`, `operator`, `value` keys in the array instead of what I had "keyless".

```
private function filterConverter($filters)
{
    $filter = [];
    foreach ($filters as $singleFilter) {
        $operator = $this->filterMap[$singleFilter['operator']];
        $value = $operator == 'LIKE' ? '%' . $singleFilter['value'] . '%' : $singleFilter['value'];

        $filter[] = [
            'key'      => $singleFilter['field'],
            'operator' => $operator,
            'value'    => $value
        ];
    }

    return $filter;
}
```

Comment: It might be worth having a look at https://github.com/Kyslik/laravel-filterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the nicest way to solve it, but this should work:

```php
private function filterConverter($filters)
{
    return collect($filters)->map(function ($filter) {  // <---
        if($filter['operator'] == 'CONTAINS')
        {
            $filter['value'] = '%' . $filter['value'] . '%';
            $filter['operator'] = 'LIKE';
        }
        else if ($filter['operator'] == 'EQUALS')
        {
            $filter['operator'] = '=';
        }

        return collect($filter)->flatten(); // <---
    })->toArray(); // <---
}
```

Here I'm using the [`Map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-map) function of the [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/collections) class. there is a [lot of useful methods](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#available-methods) provided by this class.

Comment: I have `$this->filterValues` variable which contains mappings you speak of. This is not my issue, it is that I can't forward arbitrary number of filters

Comment: Yes you can. The `where` clause accepts also an array of elements of the form: `where([['key', 'operator', 'value'],  [...])`

Comment: I am aware of multiple where clause but even if I return my values imploded by comma and between `[ ]` it doesn't get parsed right

Comment: @Norgul does your `$filers` array also contains the `key` value? (that I mentionend previosly)

Comment: @Norgul I've updated my answer in case you need an alternative. At least you have the path to solve your question. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this way

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where(function($query) use ($filter)
        {
            // You able to access $filter here
            // You may able to to generate this block by loop
            $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                  ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
        })
        ->get();
```

[Laravel Doc | Advanced Wheres](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres)

***Exp-1***

```
    $filters = [
        ['key' => 'votes', 'operator' => '>', 'value' => 100]
    ];

    DB::table('users')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
            foreach ($filters as $filter) {
                if (@$filter['key'] && @$filter['operator'] && @$filter['value']) {
                    $query->where($filter['key'], $filter['operator'], $filter['value']);
                }
            }
        })->get();
```

***Exp-2***

```
    $filters = [
        ['key' => 'votes', 'operator' => '>', 'value' => 100]
    ];

    DB::table('users')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
            foreach ($filters as $filter) {
                if (@$filter['key'] && @$filter['operator'] && @$filter['value']) {
                    $query->whereRaw("{$filter['key']} {$filter['operator']} '{$filter['value']}'");
                }
            }
        })->get();
```

> You may also use scope function [Ref](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes)

***Exp-3 Laravel Scope***

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function scopeFilter($query, $filters)
    {
        foreach ($filters as $filter) {
            if (@$filter['key'] && @$filter['value']) {
                $query->where($filter['key'], @$filter['operator']?:"=", $filter['value']);
            }
        }

        return $query;
    }
}

// Use
User::filter($filters)->get();
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't quite answer my question. I am already trying to resolve it with loops, however the format which I need to provide to `where()` is what is preventing me to do so. Even with advanced wheres I still don't know how I am supposed to format it.

Comment: @Norgul Check Exp(s)